# dockerfile golang alpine install wkhtmltopdf

Tags: go, dockerfile, wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux

i try to use this image on my go alpine. the dockerfile look like this

```
FROM surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.16.2-0.12.6-full as wkhtmltopdf
FROM golang:1.19-alpine3.17 as builder

# add some necessary packages
RUN apk update && \
    apk add libc-dev && \
    apk add gcc && \
    apk add make && \
    mkdir /src

COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltopdf
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltoimage /bin/wkhtmltoimage
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/libwkhtmltox* /bin/

WORKDIR /src
COPY ./../ ./

RUN go mod vendor && go mod verify
RUN go build -o /app-bin /src/app/api/main.go

# Distribution
FROM alpine:3
RUN apk --update add tzdata

WORKDIR /srv
COPY . .
COPY --from=builder /app-bin .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/srv/app-bin"]
```

but when i run docker build, its always return error wkhtmltopdf not found

```
> [builder 9/9] RUN go build -o /app-bin /src/app/api/main.go:
#0 94.29 # github.com/adrg/go-wkhtmltopdf
#0 94.29 vendor/github.com/adrg/go-wkhtmltopdf/converter.go:7:10: fatal error: wkhtmltox/pdf.h: No such file or directory
#0 94.29     7 | #include <wkhtmltox/pdf.h>
#0 94.29       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#0 94.29 compilation terminated.
```

---

failed to solve: process `/bin/sh -c go build -o /app-bin /src/app/api/main.go` did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
do you guys have any idea how to solve this

i tried to install `surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.16.2-0.12.6-full` to my golang alpine image but that too does not work

Comment: try adding [these additional dependencies](https://github.com/Surnet/docker-wkhtmltopdf/pkgs/container/alpine-wkhtmltopdf#other-images)

Comment: That is not actually a question about Go: the error message comes from `gcc` which was called by [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)–ostensibly in an attempt to compile some shim code to interface Go with some of the C libs supplied by `wkhtmltopdf`. As usually with C, code which uses an external library, `#include`s one or more so-called "header files" which contain declarations of the types and functions exported by that library. So, you probably need to install _some_ package(s) containing those header files for `wkhtmltopdf`…

Comment: ….something like [this](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=wkhtmltopdf-dev&branch=v3.10); see [the contents](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=v3.10&name=wkhtmltopdf-dev&arch=x86&repo=community) of that package–it contains the file `gcc` has tried to include. Note that I dunno how that relates to whatever Docker images you're using, just hoping this will provide you with the necessary clues.